# Top level Nav Dropdowns and/or Pages

Tags: mobile, menu

my challenge is to have top-level navigation items that have subnavigation and are also clickable as they are the parent pages to the sub nav

So let's say top navigation items; One, Two and Three. Subnavigation items for One are 1.1, 1.2, 1.3

Now, on desktop I know how I would handle this - show the user the sub nav on hover and still allow the user to click the top level nav but on mobile this gets a little tricky because we don't have the hover effect.

I thought about having a little chevron or visual queue next to the top-level navigation item that would toggle the display of the subnav on mobile but I think the user would still instinctively tap the word expecting the same behaviour

Sorry if that was a bit of a convoluted description. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is to put 1 on top of 1.1, 1.2 etc. You can do this on mobile but i would recommend to do the same on desktop. If you use hover on desktop to open a submenu an click does something different you might have user never discover the submenu because they click very fast. Or you might have users never discover that a click on the main menu opens another page.

[image]